# SqlDependency select today records

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldependency

I'm using SqlDependency to get changes of my records in sql server.
Select statement is based on date, and the store procedure is like this

```
Select dbo.table.dt where dbo.table.dt = @dt
```

Where @dt is passed as date parameter to stored procedure. with value DateTime.Now.Date

I want to select today records, but when the date changes from '7/14/2014' to '7/15/2014'
the records aren't changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect SQL Server to know that the date you passed in is meant to be the current date. How could it possibly tell? To SQL Server that date looks like any other date.

SQL Server will correctly notify you if records with the predicate you applied are being changed.

Issue a new SQL dependency at midnight each day.

Answer (score -1):

maybe use 
"How to: Use SQL Server Change Tracking"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305322(v=sql.110).aspx

There is sample code

---

maybe you don't use equal =  --> use >

This will produce last 24 hours changes

Select dbo.table.lastchangedate where dbo.table.lastchangedate > > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

modyfy with getdate() and getutcdate() depends what you want

lastchangedate >= DateAdd(hh, -24, GETDATE())